# how to find user location within 500 meters from given lat and long in python

Tags: python, geocoding

I want to find a user location within 500 meters from given lat and long in Python.

Given lat & long = 19.114315,72.911174

And I want to check whether new lat and long is in the range of 500 meters from given lat and long..

new lat and long = 19.112398,72.912743

I am using this formula in python..

```
math.acos(math.sin(19.114315) * math.sin(19.112398) + math.cos(19.114315) * math.cos(19.112398) * math.cos(72.912743 - (72.911174))) * 6371 <= 0.500
```

But its not giving me expected results.. Am I missing something? 
please help..

Comment: Eh, `math.sin()` as well as `math.cos()` want *radians*, not *degrees*.

Comment: Can I convert it into radians in python?

Comment: yes, you can multiply in python.
if you multiply a number in degrees, with ~ `0.0174532925` you get it in radians..  (2*PI / 360)

Comment: @user2927983 See the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875964/python-converting-radians-to-degrees). Bascially, use `math.radians(degrees)`.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I found using the python `haversine` module to be exceptionally easy and accurate enough: `from haversine import haversine; distance_km = haversine((lat_a, lng_a), (lat_b, lng_b))` .. `pip install haversine` as always ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Haversine formula to get the great-circle distance (along a sphere) between two points.  There's some problems about treating the earth like a sphere for great distances, but for 500 meters, you're probably fine (assuming that you're not trying to drop medical packages on a boat or something).

```
from math import radians, sin, cos, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, EARTH_RADIUS_KM=6372.8):

    # get distance between the points
    phi_Lat = radians(lat2 - lat1)
    phi_Long = radians(long2 - long1)

    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)

    a = sin(phi_Lat/2)**2 + \
        cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * \
        sin(phi_Long/2)**2

    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    return EARTH_RADIUS_KM * c
```

if the distance between the two points is less than your threshold, it's within the range:

```
points_1 = (19.114315,72.911174)
points_2 = (19.112398,72.912743)
threshold_km = 0.5


distance_km = haversine(points_1[0], points_1[1], points_2[0], points_2[1])
if distance_km < threshold_km:
    print('within range')
else:
    print('outside range')
```

Answer (score 0):

hint: write re-usable code, and cleanup your math.
it seems you have an error, right near the end of that formula..

`math.cos(longRad - (longRad))`  == math.cos(0) == 1

im not good with geo stuff, so I won't correct it..

```
import math

def inRangeRad(latRad, longRad):
    sinLatSqrd = math.sin(latRad) * math.sin(latRad)
    cosLatSqrd = math.cos(latRad) * math.cos(latRad)
    inner = sinLatSqrd +  cosLatSqrd * math.cos(longRad - (longRad))
    return math.acos( inner ) * 6371 <= 0.500

def inRangeDeg(latDeg, longDeg):
    latRad = 0.0174532925 * latDeg
    longRad = 0.0174532925 * longDeg
    return inRangeRad(latRad, longRad)

print "test"
print "19.114315, 72.911174"
print inRangeDeg(19.114315, 72.911174)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with this! You cannot just use `cos` and `sin` for distances using GPS coordinates, because the distance will be incorrect!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems

> In the case of plane geometry (valid for small areas on the Earth's
>   surface) the solutions to both problems reduce to simple trigonometry.
>   On the sphere, the solution is significantly more complex, e.g., in
>   the inverse problem the azimuths will differ between the two end
>   points of the connecting great circle, arc, i.e. the geodesic.

Look into [GeoPy](http://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for these calculations, you really do not want to implement that yourself.

Comment: For 500 meters, he/she will be okay.

Comment: @mirosval  I don't want exact range ,approximate range with some error is fine with me.

Comment: Maybe, but still its this kind of flawed logic that then causes problems down the line. Tomorrow I'll need to calculate bigger distances and I'll just reuse this solution having forgotten all about this...

Comment: @mirosval  Then what's the correct approach to this?

Comment: Use a library that has already solved this problem and is well tested. The GeoPy library I linked in the answer is marked as Production/Stable on PyPI. It saves you from any numeric errors you might make by reinventing the wheel and writing it yourself, plus it implements a [more accurate method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) of calculating the distance on Earth.