# showing of angle between two vector in python in degrees

Tags: python, numpy

i wrote  following program in python

```
import  math
import numpy as np

u =np.array([2,2])
v =np.array([0,3])

#alculate manualy
product =np.dot(u,v)
normu = np.linalg.norm(u)
normv = np.linalg.norm(v)
cost = product /(normu * normv)
```

what i want is to show angle  in degrees, for instance  it is equal to pi/4, what i want is to show it as  45 degrees, how can i do ? thanks in advance, i know there exist several functions, like  np.rad2deg() or np.deg2rad(), but non of them was useful or maybe i am  not using it correctly, please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: converting radians to degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875964/python-converting-radians-to-degrees)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cost` you have is not the angle. It is the cosine of the angle. You need to take the inverse cosine THEN convert radians to degrees.

```
print(np.rad2deg(np.arccos(cost)))
#45.000000000000007
```

Comment: print(math.degrees(math.acos(cost))) this is  also possible right

Comment: yes, you can use the `math` library. I only suggested `numpy` since you mentioned it in your post.