# How to calculate sinus (or any other trigonometric function) in degrees python math module?

Tags: python, function, math, module, trigonometry

How to calculate it like this?
(Or similar way):

```
import math
math.sin(in_degrees(30)
```

> > `0.5`

Comment: convert it to radians.

Comment: It is a good idea but I will be better if there would be a way to do it directly.

Comment: Isn't 30 already *in degrees*, and (as @tkausl says), you need it *in_radians*?

Comment: `def sin(deg): return math.sin(math.radians(deg))`

Comment: While this isn't a duplicate *question*, the answer provides what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9875964/535275

Comment: Thanks I thought `math.sin(math.degrees(deg))` and received it as if it would be in radians

Comment: thanks everybody it is really duplicate