# Python 3 - Issues with cosines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the following formula in Python:

[image: Image of Forumla]

The issue is with Python's `math.cos(x)`. If I do `math.cos(120)`, I get `0.8141809705265618` which is wrong. It should be -0.5.

I am new to Python so it could be something I've overlooked, but this really has me stumped.

I have written this so far: `math.sqrt(116**2+26**2-2*116*26*(math.cos(120)))`

It gives me `96.02531117254335` which is incorrect, it should be 130.95037.

Any ideas on fixing this?

Comment: convert deg to rad

Comment: the 120 means 120 radians, not 120 degrees

Comment: No, that's definitely [the right answer](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cos%28120%29). As mentioned, `cos` takes numbers in radians. [as per its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.acos), so if you're working in degrees: [convert them](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#angular-conversion).

Comment: You are mixing degrees and radian

Comment: Using `math.radians(math.cos(120))` gives me `0.014210138642771413` though

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9877360/12491124). You need to change degrees to radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert your degree angle in radians:

```py
math.sqrt(116**2+26**2-2*116*26*(math.cos(math.radians(120))))
```

Comment: Yes! Yes!  Thank you sir, that's it! I was trying the two the other way (`math.radians(math.cos(120))`)