# Python PIL - drawing line does not work as expected

Tags: python, math

I would like to draw a straight line on 640 x 640 image. Having start of the line coordinates (x1,y1) , length of the line in pixels 'length' and angle 'angle' I need to calculate end of the line coordinates (x2,y2).
For this I wrote function calc_x2y2.  It works as expected for 0 (zero) angle drawing straight line to the right of the screen but is not working for 90 degrees which should be straight down line while it's more to the left looks like around 110 degree (picture below). What am I doing wrong?

```
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def calc_x2y2(length, angle, x1,y1):
    x2 = x1 + math.cos(angle)*length
    y2 = y1 + math.sin(angle)*length
    return (x2,y2)

w, h = 640, 640
x1,y1 = w/2, h/2
shape = [(x1,y1), calc_x2y2(300,90,x1,y1)]
# creating new Image object
img = Image.new("RGB", (w, h),(225,225,225))
# create line on the image
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img1.line(shape, fill="#401eba", width=5)
img.show()
```

[Straight line that should be 90 degree except it's not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taJoX.png)

Comment: Angles are expressed in radians, not degrees. Divide your angle by 180, and multiple with pi (or use a conversion function)

Comment: Have you checked whether `calc_x2y2` produces the results you expect? Hint: it doesn't, therefore you can easily eliminate the rest of your drawing code as the culprit. This leads you more or less straigt to @Stefan's comment...

Comment: Works perfectly ! Many thanks. For anyone reading this post searching similar answer code should be amended to calculate the radians like this radius = 90 / 180 * np.pi where np is the numpy and than 'radius' variable added where calc_x2y2 function is called  like this calc_x2y2(300,radius,x1,y1).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9877360/5987