# Calculate coordinates of end point of a line by having the angle and the length

Tags: python, math

I have the coordinates of the start point of a line and also i have the angle and length of that line and i want to get the coordinates of the endpoint.

I am using the script:

```
X_B = X_A + (length * round(abs(math.cos(Angle))))
Y_B = Y_A + (length * round(abs(math.sin(Angle))))
```

But in many cases it doesnt work!

Comment: Why are you rounding the result? Also, could you provide us a SPECIFIC case in which this approach does not work?

Comment: what are the cases in which it "doesn't work"? in what way "doesn't it work"?

Comment: because sometimes it made wrong answers.

Comment: rounding sin or cos will return 0 or 1.... did you mean to `round(length*sin..)`? and why round anyway?

Comment: `abs` is also unnecessary: the only points you will get correct are the ones above and right of your starting point.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. Show some values that can be used for `length` and `Angle` to get a wrong answer. Show what the answer should be, and give your explanation for why that is the correct answer. Show what the answer is instead, and explain how it is different.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875964/how-can-i-convert-radians-to-degrees-with-python answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the angle is in **radians**, not in *degrees*:

```
import math 

length = 1
Angle = 3.14/3
X_A = 0
Y_A = 0

X_B = X_A + round(length * math.cos(Angle), 3)
Y_B = Y_A + round(length * math.sin(Angle), 3)

print(X_B, Y_B)
```

**Output:** *Also, don't round `sin` or `cos`. Perform the round on the resulting value.*

```
0.5 0.866
```

Comment: rounding sin or cos makes no sense... and why abs? using `abs` you will only get the points correct that are above and on the right of the starting point.

Comment: @hiro-protagonist He might want to round the result to 2 place decimals. But you're right, not sine or cosine

Comment: Why are you using `abs`?

Comment: someone told me to do that

Comment: @hehe-boi Did this answer work for your problem?

Comment: you could use [`math.radians`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians) for the conversion from degrees to radians...